# Angular - UI Router - Nested States - Browser Back button does not work as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a scenario where I have the following nested states structure:

```
root
  root.item1
  root.item2
```

The `root` state has a template showing some variables that are set in child states. Also it needs to run first because it has logic that determines which child state will be loaded.

In case `root` determines that `root.item2` needs to be loaded the flow of events is:

```
exec root -> redirect to root.item2 -> exec root.item2
```

Now if at this point we redirect to `root.item1` and them press Browser Back button, I'd expect to be redirected to `root.item2`, but instead it looks like  url just gets cleared out and you do not see any child state loaded at all.

Here is a [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SeVsrmrkEejpjORp4DqL?p=preview) that shows the issue.

**Steps to reproduce the issue in the Plunker:**

1. Let it load `root.item2`
2. Click `Go to Detail 1`
3. Observe that you are on `root.item1`
4. Click Browser Back button
5. Observe that you are not on `root.item2`

Submitted [Issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1888) to the UI Router's Gihub page. Hopefully some help will come from there.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Code that shows the issue:

```js
angular
.module('historyApp', [
  'ui.router'
]) 
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('root', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<h1>Parent</h1> <div>{{vm.title}}</div> <div ui-view></div>',
        controller: function($scope, $state){
            $scope.vm = { title: '' };
            // some conditional login that determines which child state will be loaded:
            var variableChildState = 'root.detail2';
            $state.go(variableChildState);
        }
      })
      .state('root.detail1', {
        url: '/detail1',
        template: '<h1>Detail 1</h1><a ui-sref="root.detail2">Go to Detail 2</a>',
        controller: function($scope, $state){
            $scope.vm.title = 'Set in 1';
        }
      })
      .state('root.detail2', {
        url: '/detail2',
        template: '<h1>Detail 2</h1><a ui-sref="root.detail1">Go to Detail 1</a>',
        controller: function($scope, $state){
            $scope.vm.title = 'Set in 2';
        }
      })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }
])
.run(function($rootScope, $location){

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
      function (event, toState, toParams){
        console.log(toState)
      });
})
;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="historyApp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.10/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: its firing `$stateChangeStart` event on my end

Comment: You right, it does fire it. It just does not redirect back to the child state that you were on. I updated question

Comment: the controller for the root state only loads once when the page loads. if you add a `console.log($state);` to this controller you can see it logs once when the page loads then going to state1 and hitting back in the browser does not cause it to log the state again as the controller does not reload.

Comment: @gonkan Yeah, I don't need the controller on the `root` to execute every time. Just once during the loading. This seems to behave as expected. I updated question with "Steps to reproduce the issue".

Comment: but it only runs the code within when it loads, which contains your code to change the state to `root.item2`, so the state doesn't change when the browser back button is pressed, this is what would be expected, no? Unless I am missing what you're getting at.

Comment: @gonkan I only need to determine which child state is loaded once, during the initial load. After that I leave it to the user to navigate between child states. Please follow steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I see the point in case plunkr goes down, but it seems to me that the fact of creating the plunkr is the "the act of producing a minimal, complete, verifiable example". Anyway, I'm not going to argue this. This is a topic to discuss in metadata. I updated the question. Please "Unhold"

Comment: @Dmitry the code that changes the state in the root state actually needs to fire twice if you want the back button to work as you expect. I was following the steps you gave anyway. The code in that controller only runs once, not when the back button is pressed so you wouldn't expect to end up at your last step as the `$state.go()` that switches you to the child state is not run. Not sure I can explain it any other way.

Comment: @gonkan Think you are a user. Forget about the code. What you see is that you are on Page `root.item2`. You click "Go to `root.item1`". You get there. You click Back button. You expect to be on `root.item2` because that where you were initially, but you are not there.

Comment: @Dmitry I think when you flick state like that it's not registered in the browser history in the way it is when you click a link, the URL has stayed the same, as far as it's concerned you are still in the `root` state. So when you go back that's where you end up.

Comment: @gonkan the url actually changes. You just can't see it in the plunker because of how they embed things in the iFrames. If you run this code locally you'll see that initial url is `/detail2`. Then `/detail1`. And after pressing back button it's a `/`

Comment: @Dmitry for some reason that call to $state.go does not regiester a new entry in the browser history, observe history.length value in the console: http://plnkr.co/edit/Sh9Ulx4cgsCwzxqpZtpJ?p=preview, question is do you just want to get it done as in get around it - there would be ways or want to investigate more, maybe even dig into ui-router code to find out why...

Comment: @user2847643 Well, I'm out of ideas, so a workaround might be enough for me. What do you have in mind?

Comment: You could just listen to `$stateChangeSuccess` and record the last state for yourself. I also found there is a `location: 'replace'` option to `$state.go` which should cause history to be updated (or i'm reading the docs wrong) but I can't make it work.

Comment: Like if the last state was 'root' and we are going to 'root.whatever' insert 'root.whatever' into history. Although that is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a simple syntax solution:

```
.state('root.detail1', {
    url: 'detail1',
    template: '<h1>Detail 1</h1><a ui-sref="root.detail2">Go to Detail 2</a>',
    controller: function($scope, $state){
        $scope.vm.title = 'Set in 1';
    }
  })
```

Notice: **url: 'detail1'** instead of url: '/detail1'

Hope that helps.